# web-scraping an unordered table

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape with BeautifulSoup then print it out in Pandas, but the table I need to work with is having spans randomly every month.

"https://to.sze.hu/kezdolap" the top table in the middle div

The path is `soup.select("#content > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > table")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```py
df_list = pd.read_html('https://to.sze.hu/kezdolap', header=0)
```

Which will add your tables to a list, then simply:

```py
df_list[0]
```

Gives you:

```
    Ügyfélfogadás NAPPALI tagozatos hallgatók számára (full time students)  Ügyfélfogadás NAPPALI tagozatos hallgatók számára (full time students).1    Ügyfélfogadás NAPPALI tagozatos hallgatók számára (full time students).2
0   2021. augusztus 25-augusztus 27./ 25. August -...   szerda/Wednesday    9.30-11.00
1   2021. augusztus 25-augusztus 27./ 25. August -...   csütörtök/Thursday  13.00-14.30
2   2021. augusztus 25-augusztus 27./ 25. August -...   péntek/Friday   13.00-14.30
3   2021. augusztus 30-szeptember 3./ 30. August -...   kedd/Tuesday    9.30-11.00
4   2021. augusztus 30-szeptember 3./ 30. August -...   csütörtök/Thursday  13.00-14.30
5   2021. augusztus 30-szeptember 3./ 30. August -...   péntek/Friday   13.00-14.30
6   2021. szeptember 6-17. / 06. September-17. Sep...   kedd/Tuesday    9.30 – 11.00
7   2021. szeptember 6-17. / 06. September-17. Sep...   csütörtök/Thursday  13.00 – 14.30
8   2021. szeptember 20-30. / 20-30 September 2021  kedd/Tuesday    10.00 – 11.00
9   2021. szeptember 20-30. / 20-30 September 2021  szerda/Wednesday    10.00 – 11.00
10  2021. szeptember 20-30. / 20-30 September 2021  szerda/Wednesday    13.00 – 14.00
11  2021. szeptember 20-30. / 20-30 September 2021  csütörtök/Thursday  10.00 - 11.00
```